# Applying cut off ranges to an variable in the objective function in linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, self-learning

I started learning linear programming to solve a personal challenge but I cannot formulate the model. This is not for a class but for something I am personally working on. I can do the simple optimization examples but this is above me currently.

I have data on *j* (actually 3) categories of people *P*. Each category has a score ranging from 0 to 100. I have the individual people, which category, and their scores.

There are *i* (actually 4) score cutoffs *C* ranges.  There are *i* (4) values *V* which are dependent on the score range.

- $V_1$ is applied to number of people in any category with score <= $C_1$
- $V_2$ is applied to number of people in any category with score > $C_1$ &&
  <= $C_2$
- $V_3$ is applied to number of people in any category with score >
  $C_2$ && <= $C_3$
- $V_4$ is applied to number of people in any category with
  score > $C_3$
- 0 <= $C_i$ <= 100 (alignment to the scores)
- 500 <= $V_1$ <= $V_2$ <= $V_3$ <= $V_4$ <= 100000

I need to determine V and C to maximize the equation

$$\max \sum (V_i * P_{1i}) - (2 * V_i * P_{2i}) - (V_i * P_{3i})$$
    where $V_i$ is the value in the i cutoff range and $P_{ji}$ is the number of people in the *j* category with a score in the *i* cutoff range.

I have a few sticking points - how to sync $V_i$ and $C_i$ and how to select the correct $P_{ji}$ for the *C_i* cutoff range. I believe I need to restructure the data, perhaps some boolean multiplication, but my experience does not cover that part yet. Soon hopefully

I eventually will place this into cvxopt. Currently I am want to write the model in standard form so I understand it. If I do not understand it, I cannot program it.

Any help or pointers of where to look for is appreciated.

Thank you